# Origin capacitor://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ios, angular, amazon-s3, capacitor, ionic5

I want download file on my ionic mobile app from amazon S3 but I have this issue `Origin capacitor://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

So I add  `"capacitor://localhost"` on my CORS configuration on amazon S3 like this :

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "HEAD",
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*",
        "capacitor://localhost"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

but I have always the same issue.

My download function :

```
async downloadResource(filename: string) {

  try {

    this.url = this.changeSpecialCharacter(this.urlFolder + filename);
    let extention = this.getFileExtension(filename);

    filename = this.getFileName(filename);

    if (!filename.includes(extention)) {
      filename = filename + '.' + extention;
    }

    if (!filename) filename = this.url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
    
    const response = await fetch(this.url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Origin': 'capacitor://localhost'
      }),
      mode: 'cors'
    });
    console.log(' response '+JSON.stringify(response));
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(' blobUrl '+JSON.stringify(response));
    const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: filename,
      data: blobUrl,
      directory: Directory.Documents,
      encoding: Encoding.UTF8
    });

    console.log('File written', result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error fetch '+e);
  }
}
```

I test also with      `const response = await fetch("https://file-examples.com/storage/feeb72b10363daaeba4c0c9/2017/10/file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg", {mode: 'cors'});`  I have the same issue. So the problem is from the device